# AUCTeX preview font size too small

Tags: emacs, windows, auctex, preview

I have Emacs 24 and AUCTex on a Windows 7 machine, however the preview font size is just way too small. Is there a way to make them bigger?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to put the cursor on the formula? If yes, I'd try M-x customize-face RET.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the following to your `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(set-default 'preview-scale-function 1.2)
```

Adjust the value according to your needs.

Comment: Using the `px` package from `packages-list-packages`, this trick doesn't work for changing the font size. Does anyone know why not / what would work?

Answer (score 0):

px package uses org-latex, so you can change the preview font size using the scale attribute of the org-format-latex-options settings.
I changed it from 1.0 to 1.6. It looks much better.