# Preview latex size not changing

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview

I have found that the equation preview sizes with preview-latex don't work, despite changing preview-scale-function with the following, for example:

```
(custom-set-variables '(preview-scale-function 2.0))
```

in ~/.emacs. No matter what I set this value, the output is as follows, with very small equations:

[image]

What am I likely doing wrong here? For reference, this is on Ubuntu 22.04, with AucTex installed through the emacs 27.1 package installer.

I am aware of the following [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110819/auctex-preview-font-size-too-small) here, which seems to be about precisely the issue I have been having. However, the answers there do not help here.

Answer (score 0):

`preview-scale-function` should not be a numerical value, but instead a function that returns a value.  What you want is instead the following:

`(custom-set-variables '(preview-scale-function (lambda () 2.0))`

I'll take this opportunity to plug my package [preview-tailor](https://github.com/ultronozm/preview-tailor.el), which makes it easy to adjust preview scales (in a monitor-dependent way, and compatibly with text scale, etc)